# Display real time results in input box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the results of an input in real time in another disabled input box and am not having much luck. Code below:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('input');

inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = inputBox.value*2;
}

<input type='text' id='input'>

<input type='text' id='output' disabled>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a listener and use value instead of innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);

var inputBox = document.getElementById('input');

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('output').value = inputBox.value*2;
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/22t37834/

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run this code: null is not an object (evaluating.getElementByid('input').addEventListener')

Comment: Ok, I order the code correctly and all working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'keyup' as it is fired after the char is entered.

```
$("#input").keyup (function (e) {
     $('#output').val($(this).val() * 2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one -

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('input');

inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = inputBox.value*2;
   var val = document.getElementById('input').value
  document.getElementById('output').value = val;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input'>

<input type='text' id='output' disabled>
```